# Using SetDisplayConfig to enable a secondary display

Tags: winapi, windows-7

I am trying to use the Windows CCD APIs (SetDisplayConfig) to enable a secondary monitor, but haven't figured out how to do it. I've been successful at re-positioning and disabling displays, but haven't found any examples of how to enable a previously disabled monitor.

Does anybody have experience with this? I've found other questions showing how to do it with ChangeDisplaySettingsEx, but I'm trying to use SetDisplayConfig.